# Sending email with AWS SES without custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, devise, amazon-ses

I would like to send email from a Rails 5.1 app with AWS SES through smtp, but without using a custom domain (it's ok if users receive emails with an address from aws). But when searching through AWS documentation or google, I can only find instructions to use custom domains.

Is it possible? And if yes, what email address (mail FROM) should be used to replace the placeholder in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a custom domain, but you do need to have at least an email address you can verify following the procedure outlined in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

AWS doesn't have "default" email addresses to use for sending mails. Note also, that SES require you to handle bounces and such.